# Symmetric Bernoulli distribution from non-symmetric Bernoulli distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have this question that may look trivial but it made me frustrated. I have a Bernoulli distribution

$$x=\begin{cases}1 &\text{with probability}\quad P(x=1)=\mu \\ 0 &\text{with probability}\quad P(x=0)=1-\mu\end{cases}=\mu^x(1-\mu)^{1-x}$$

Now I am trying to find the transformation $y=f(x)$ which gives me the following distribution

$$y=\begin{cases}1 &\text{with probability}\quad P(y=1)=\frac{1+\mu}{2} \\ -1 &\text{with probability}\quad P(y=-1)=\frac{1-\mu}{2}\end{cases}=\left(\frac{1+\mu}{2} \right)^{\frac{1+y}{2}}\left(\frac{1-\mu}{2} \right)^{\frac{1-y}{2}}$$

I can not find the transformation that gives me new distribution. Does the transformation need to be stochastic (by that I mean $y=f(x,s)$ for some random variable $s$) because $y=f(x)$ with deterministic $f$ seems not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy but nice

1) Let's define a new random variable (toss a coin)

$$\mathbb{P}(S) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{2},  & \text{if $S=0$ } \\
\frac{1}{2}, & \text{if $S=1$ }
\end{cases}$$

2) calculate the variable $X+S$ and define

$$Y=1-2\cdot\mathbb{1}_{\{0\}}(X+S)$$

This is what you need:in fact it gives the following distribution

$$\mathbb{P}(Y) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1-\mu}{2},  & \text{if $Y=-1$ } \\
\frac{1+\mu}{2}, & \text{if $Y=1$ }
\end{cases}$$

Comment: Thank you! very neato! I have two questions regards this, why the transform $y=2\times x -1$ won't work and second one is how did you find the right transform? It is not hard when you see the right transform but tha't just after puzzle solved xD, If I thought about it, I never arrived at the transform you defined, where to look and study to learn this techniques, btw i studied stochastic process by Papoulis but still have problems with this type (this was an exercise from machine learning and pattern recognition by Bishop).

Comment: Any deterministic transformation will not work because you want to change also probabilities and not only the values of the support. I simply used an auxiliary variable to divide by 2 the probability $P(X=0)$

Comment: Sorry for long comment above, I mean is there any systematic and algorithmic way to find such transforms? The reference to study suffices, thank you.

Comment: @K.K.McDonald : I think that it is enough a certain practice in exercises, day by day in order to improve your brainstorming in these little tricks. I do not exclude that there are other  possible ways to get your transformation.